# import data from adwords to sql server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, google-ads-api

I am trying to import data from AdWords, when I set it up, I always receive a link to a report, not a file.

Is there any way of receiving a csv instead of a link? If a receive a file I can easily automate the insert with powershell, I can’t do much with a link (I don’t feel comfortable using Selenium or a tool alike to consume that).

This is my screen with options:

[image]

Comment: Is this link to file or website? Would Invoke-WebRequest work for you? You could download file or parse returned html to get what you need in either scenarios

Comment: _Is there any way of receiving a csv instead of a link?_ I think your question is more likely to address adwords than PowerShell

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I wasn’t aware of Invoke-WebRequest. If I click the link the file starts downloading automatically… I have never used it, can I use Invoke-WebRequest and pass my google credentials?

Comment: Surely you can. I do not have ready to use recipe, but maybe this would help you https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/55115de5e8b366be3969b24884f30a39